# How to overlay a Lottie Animation in Constraint layout in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, lottie

I have a constraint layout, it has a progress bar in center, once the progress bar reached 100,I need to use Lottie animation to show animation, that animation should overlay the existing Progress bar.

I tried to add the Lottie animation inside a View, and have the view in same constraint layout as progress bar, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to set their visibility ?
Every `View` has a `.visibility`, you can hide the progress bar when it reaches 100% and show your Lottie animation right after, without going for overlays or other things.

```
val progressbar = findViewById<...>(R.id.progress_bar)
val lottieAnimation = findViewById<...>(R.id.lottie_animation)
...

// When the progressbar reaches 100%
progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
lottieAnimation.visibility = View.VISIBLE

// Start the animation
```

Remember to set correctly the `ProgressBar` and the `Lottie` views `visibility` respectively to `visible` and `gone` in the xml file.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" <--- This
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Lottie
    android:id="@+id/lottie_animation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" <--- This
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

If this doesn't solve your problem please let me know and provide the code that's not working, happy coding!

Comment: I needs to Show both progress bar and Lottie animation,  the Lottie animation should overlay the progress bar

Comment: Can you provide some code ?